# How to convert dates to quarters in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I would like to convert my date column into an indicator of the quarter of that particular year, say `2018q1` or `2018q2` etc.

My data looks like this, I have stock returns once per quarter (not showing the return column here), and a corresponding date, the column quarter is what I would like to get (or something similar)

```
data = [
    {'date': '3/22/18', 'quarter': 1},
    {'date': '3/22/18', 'quarter': 1}, 
    {'date': '6/22/18', 'quarter': 3},
    {'date': '6/22/18', 'quarter': 3},
    {'date': '9/22/18', 'quarter': 2},
    {'date': '9/22/18', 'quarter': 2}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['s1', 's2','s1','s2','s1','s2'])

        date  quarter
 s1  3/22/13   2013q1
 s2  3/24/13   2013q1
 s1  6/21/13   2013q2
 s2  6/26/13   2013q2
 s1  9/21/13   2013q3
 s2  9/28/13   2013q3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandas has a method to help you, it's called `pd.PeriodIndex(monthcolumn, freq= 'Q')`. You may need to convert your month column to datatype first by using datetime libray.

Pandas also have a method called `'to_date'` that you can use to convert a column to a date column.

For example:

```
df["year"] = pd.to_date(df["year"])
```

Answer (score 41):

**`to_datetime`**:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

**`PeriodIndex`**

```
df['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.date, freq='Q')

         date quarter
s1 2018-03-22  2018Q1
s2 2018-03-22  2018Q1
s1 2018-06-22  2018Q2
s2 2018-06-22  2018Q2
s1 2018-09-22  2018Q3
s2 2018-09-22  2018Q3
```

Comment: Is there any way in pandas to define from which month my quarter starts?

Answer (score 25):

#### [Series.dt.to_period](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['quarter'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('Q')

         date quarter
s1 2018-03-22  2018Q1
s2 2018-03-22  2018Q1
s1 2018-06-22  2018Q2
s2 2018-06-22  2018Q2
s1 2018-09-22  2018Q3
s2 2018-09-22  2018Q3
```

Comment: Is there any way in pandas to define from which month my quarter starts?

Answer (score 11):

`datecolumn.dt.quarter` feature will help.

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df["Quarter"] = df.date.dt.quarter
```

Answer (score 4):

Just extract the month part of your date string. The quarter can simply be obtained through `(month - 1) // 3 + 1`.

Since your data is a dictionary whose `'date'` key is a `str` of form `(\d{1:2})/(\d{1:2})/(\d\d)`, you can get the "month" part of the date (the first group), convert it to an int, and use `(month - 1) // 3 + 1` to get the quarter.

Extracting the month part of the date string can be done using regex or even simple string slicing. The quarter therefore ranges from 1 to 4 and is determined by:

- `m // 3` is 0 for `0 <= m <= 2` (Q1)
- `m // 3` is 1 for `3 <= m <= 5` (Q2)
- `m // 3` is 2 for `6 <= m <= 8` (Q3)
- `m // 3` is 3 for `9 <= m <= 11` (Q4)

where `m = month - 1`

Answer (score 1):

## .date will not work as it is a function of data frame.

```
df_q8['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_q8['Date'])
df_q8['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df_q8['Date'] ,freq='Q')
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to extract the quarter number is as below.

```
In [56]: datetime.date.today()
Out[56]: datetime.date(2021, 10, 20)

In [57]: ts = pd.Timestamp(datetime.date.today()).quarter

In [58]: ts
Out[58]: 4
```