# Pandas - Boolean value conditional statement not being picked up in function

Tags: python, pandas

New to python.

I have a dataset containing a date column formatted as yyyy-mm-dd (%Y%m%d) as datetime64 type. The dataset spans 2 years 2019-2020. I'm trying to write a function that will add the quarter based on the date. I can't get the if statements to recognize the data so everything is coming back as 'Q42020' and I don't understand why.

```
def applyquarter(x):
        if 'date' < '2019-04-01':
            return('Q12019')
        elif 'date' < '2019-07-01':
            return('Q22019')
        elif 'date' < '2019-10-01':
            return('Q32019')
        elif 'date' < '2020-01-01':
            return('Q42019')
        elif 'date' < '2020-04-01':
            return('Q12020')
        elif 'date' < '2020-07-01':
            return('Q22020')
        elif 'date' < '2020-10-01':
            return('Q32020')
        else: 
            return('Q42020')
```

My understanding:

if/elif/else statements run until the criteria is met, then stop running

datetime64 can be used with boolean operators

the problem must exist in the boolean interaction with the datetime value

Would anyone please explain what I'm not understanding correctly?

Comment: Your function takes a variable x (presumably a value) so you want to compare `x` with your date, i..e `if x < '2019-04-01':` Otherwise the comparison is a static comparison of the string `'date'` with the other string and disregards your value.

Comment: On the other hand, there's no need for `Series.apply` here it's both inefficient and a wall of code. If you provide some sample data it's very easy to get your output with the built-in datetime attributes (literally just `df['date'].dt.to_period('Q')`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if 'date' < '2019-04-01':
```

This compares two character strings.  Nothing in your posted code makes *any* reference to a data frame.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459301/how-to-convert-dates-to-quarters-in-python#50459364) for converting a date to a quarter.  The critical call is

```
pd.PeriodIndex(df.date, freq='Q')
```

Comment: Turns out what I didn't understand was there was something built in that handles that exact issue. Thanks for the PeriodIndex info, new one to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution

```
date2check=date.today()
dd=((date2check - pd.offsets.QuarterBegin(startingMonth=4))).date()
if dd.month//3 !=0:
    qtrnum =dd.month//3
    yy=dd.year
else:
    qtrnum =4
    yy=dd.year - 1
qname = "Q"+str(qtrnum)+str(yy)
qname
```

output:

```
'Q42020'
```