# Pandas: Converting month range to YYYY- Qx

Tags: python, pandas

Input df(Date column)

```
Date
Jul - Sep 2017
Oct - Dec 2017
Jan - Mar 2018
Apr - Jun 2018
Jul - Sep 2018
Oct - Dec 2018
Jan - Mar 2019
Apr - Jun 2019
Jul - Sep 2019
Oct - Dec 2019
```

Expected Output

```
Date
2017-Q3
2017-Q4
2018-Q1
2018-Q2
2018-Q3
2018-Q4
2019-Q1
2019-Q2
.
.
.
```

How do I achieve the above conversion for `Date` column in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert dates to quarters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459301/how-to-convert-dates-to-quarters-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `str.split()`,`to_datetime()`,`to_period()` and `strftime()` method:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.split('-').str[1]).dt.to_period('Q').dt.strftime('%Y-Q%q')
```

output of `df`:

```
    Date
0   2017-Q3
1   2017-Q4
2   2018-Q1
3   2018-Q2
4   2018-Q3
5   2018-Q4
6   2019-Q1
7   2019-Q2
8   2019-Q3
9   2019-Q4
```